# Generalised Reed Solomon Codes Examples

Tags: coding-theory

Generalised Reed Solomon codes are defined as follow:

[image]

From the definition, what is the range of $f$? Will any $f$ do? Also, what does $v_if(\alpha_i)$ mean? Does it mean multiplication in finite field? If possible, can someone give me an example of such code?

Comment: It looks like the $\alpha_i$ and $v_i$ are fixed, and $f$ varies over all polynomials of degree less than $k$ with coefficients in the field $\mathbf{F}_q$.

Comment: I guess the range of $f$ is $\mathbb{F}_q$. So $v_if(\alpha_i)$ is multiplication in finite field

Comment: Yes. The vectors $\alpha$ and $v$ are fixed and have components in $\mathbf{F}_q$. Polynomials with coefficients in that field evaluated at points in the same fields obviously have values there, too. You are both right. Everything happens in $\mathbf{F}_q$.